# Count all pairs of x,y such as x + y = c && x XOR y = d

Tags: combinatorics, counting

> Given two decimals $c$ and $d$;  $1 \le c,d \le 10^{12}$. Count all pairs of $x$ and $y$ that satisfy the following statements:
>   $$
> x+y = c\\
> x \text{ XOR } y = d
> $$

Killed already a day still can't solve that task in 2s. Even with optimizations brute-force algorithm doesn't terminate when $c$ and $d$ closer to upper bound.

**UPDATE**
Took a while to figure, here is solution:

```
void solve( Scanner in, PrintWriter out ) {
    long sum = in.nextLong();
    long xor = in.nextLong();

    long andMask = andMask( sum, xor );
    if( andMask == -1 ) {
        out.print( 0 );
        return;
    }

    long sample = sample( sum, andMask );
    if( sample == -1 ) {
        out.print( 0 );
        return;
    }

    out.print( combinations( sample, andMask ) );

}

long andMask( long sum, long xor ) {
    if( ( sum - xor ) % 2 != 0 ) return -1;
    return ( sum - xor ) / 2;
}

long sample( long sum, long andMask ) {
    if( ( ( sum - andMask ) & andMask ) != andMask ) return -1;
    return sum - andMask;
}

long combinations( long sample, long andMask ) {
    long combinations = 1;
    int major = major( sample );
    for( int i = 0; i < major; i++ ) {
        if( bitValue( sample, i ) == 1 && bitValue( andMask, i ) != 1 ) {
            combinations *= 2;
        }
    }

    if( andMask == 0 ) {
        combinations -= 2;
    }
    return combinations;
}

int major( long sum ) {
    int major = 0;
    while( sum > 0 ) {
        major++;
        sum = sum >> 1;
    }
    return major;
}

int bitValue( long value, int bit ) {
    return ( int ) ( value >> bit & 1 );
}
```

Comment: And what is the question? Community votes, please: is this unclear?

Comment: @Raphael questions is how to do w/o brute-force iteration and checks

Comment: If $x \mathop{XOR} y = d$, then $y = d \mathop{XOR} x$, so...

Comment: @Macchiatow I can't even tell from your post if you are interested in a solution for this here system (i.e. this is a combinatorics question) or if you want an algorithm that can count such things more generally.

Comment: @Raphael i don't need a solutions for the system rather for a concrete case, let's say c = 9 and d = 5 answer is 4. because following combinations possible (2, 7), (3, 6), (6, 3), (7, 2)

Comment: @Macchiatow Could you also share how can we get all the values for x and y under 2 seconds.

Comment: @Rudrani getting all values of x and y would be brute force and can never work under 2 sec. I rather check possibility of combination iterating over bits. This works extremely fast. Please pay attention to the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $x+y=(x \text{ XOR } y)+2(x \text{ AND } y)$.

Comment: took me a lot to figure end solution, yet your hint was major :)

Comment: If you liked my hint, you could also upvote my answer.